# SemaphoreCI instability when downloading big maven dependencies

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, semaphore-ci

[We are using SemaphoreCI as continuous-integration](https://github.com/IllinoisCogComp/illinois-cogcomp-nlp). Some of our maven dependencies are pretty big (like order of hundreds of megabytes).

A behavior that we are observing is that, our builds fails often due to failures in downloading the dependencies; we have to restart it once or twice to make it pass, in order to move on, which is really annoying.

I wonder if anyone has any suggestions/experiences regarding this problems.

Answer (score 1):

Milana from SemaphoreCI here.

It would be good to cache these dependencies between builds. If your project is recognized as a Maven project on Semaphore, related dependencies will be cached by default. For such a project Semaphore caches `~/.m2` directory. To read more about this please refer to [this page](https://semaphoreci.com/docs/caching-between-builds.html).

If you're still experiencing similar issue or if you would like to learn more about SemaphoreCI, please send us an email at [support@semaphoreci.com](http://support@semaphoreci.com) and we'll do our best to help you out!

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Unlike what is says, almost always it downloads the dependencies, for my sbt project. Supposedly all of the dependencies should be in `.ivy` (which should be cached by default) but the behavior is otherwise.